# Case sensitive on restrictions 'equals id' in Hibernate restrictions

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

I try to do a case sensitive equals on `username` with Hibernate (3.6.9) but it seems that the restriction is case insensitive.
For example: "AdMin" or "admin" is both valid but only "admin" should be correct and otherwise `.size()` should return 0. I would try to avoid using `like`. Somebody got a different solution?

Code:

```
Session sess = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Login> logins = sess.createCriteria(Login.class).add(Restrictions.idEq(username)).list();
if(logins.size() == 1) {
    return logins.get(0);
} else {            
    return null;
}
```

Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL doesn't make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change table definition. In case of Mysqsl you need to alter your `username` column to `binary or varbinary` instead of `char/varchar` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html). For SQLServer, make sure `username` uses case-sensitive collation (see [list of sql collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx))

Comment: I was afraid of this answer. There are already a lot of applications deployed on different databases so this solution will cost a lot of time ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround:

```
    Login login = (Login) getHibernateTemplate().get(Login.class, username);
    if(login != null && !login.getUsername().equals(username)){
        return null;
    }
    return login;
```