# Hibernate Example ignores case without calling Example.ignoreCase()

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using *Hibernate version 4.3.5.Final*.  The problem here is that Hibernate finds entities of the type `Foo` where the case of the property `address` has different a case (e.g. "BLAFOO"). However, in my example, `ex.ignoreCase()` is not called.

I only want to find entities which match the exact case.  What am i doing wrong?

```
Foo myBean = new Foo();
myBean.setAddress("blaFoo");
Example ex = Example.create(myBean);
ex.excludeZeroes();
//ex.ignoreCase();
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class).add(ex);   
List<MonitoredApp> apps = dao.findByDetachedCriteria(crit);
```

Comment: Using MySQL? Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case sensitive Search in Hibernate Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030921/case-sensitive-search-in-hibernate-criteria)

Comment: Ultimately it depends on filed collation of db - if it's '_ci' (case-insensitive) or '_cs' (case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by a case insensitive comparison at the database itself.

Check the character set/collation of your table/database.