# how to make toUpperCase in hibernate Restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I wrote my code like this

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("lastName", "ChARaN").ignoreCase()); //
```

This by default converting both to lower case.

SQL generated:

```
select
    this_.ID as ID1_0_0_,
    this_.EMAIL as EMAIL2_0_0_,
    this_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NA3_0_0_,
    this_.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAM4_0_0_ 
from
    Employee this_ 
where
    lower(this_.LAST_NAME)=?

    14:56:57,017 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [charan]
```

I want Hibernate to generate query for uppercase like:

```
where
       upper(this_.LAST_NAME)=?
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030921/case-sensitive-search-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: @Charan But what difference does it make? I don't think the outcome be any different for equals operator as long as both side are using either upper or lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what advantage would it have if it uses `UPPER` instead of `LOWER`. Having said that you try below option to force Hibernate to use `UPPER`

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("UPPER({alias}.lastName) = UPPER(?)", "ChaRaN", StringType.INSTANCE))
```

Comment: if we have a index on that column, i would like to know how can i use criteria..... yes i already tried with sqlRestriction, that works,i know....,, but i am looking for any in build one if any

Comment: @Charan At least with criteria api I don't think if there is any such in-built function. But then, how is index related to your criteria api?

Comment: index is created on that column with uppercase to fetch records fast in a huge data table... so i want to fetch with uppercase of that column,, no other go... :( .... at the same time i am not a fan of sqlRestrictions... if we are using hibernate, lets code fully in hibernate, sqlRestriction is something like native sqls

Comment: @Charan the other option is going wit HQL, that has an in-built upper function.