# findByCriteria returning values by ignoring case

Tags: java, hibernate

i am using following code to check user.

```
DetachedCriteria queryCriteria = DetachedCriteria
queryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("UserName", userObj.getUserName().trim()));
userList = htObj.findByCriteria(queryCriteria);
```

where userobj is user object passes from backing bean

the problem is that it returns result without type restriction,
e.g. though i enter 'admin' as username and there is 'ADMIN' in database it matches the record

Comment: This is not a Spring nor a JSF problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies more in the database than in the criteria query :  check [Case sensitive on restrictions 'equals id' in Hibernate restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066143/case-sensitive-on-restrictions-equals-id-in-hibernate-restrictions) and configure your database accordingly.

Comment: thanx .. . i got my answer from this link, the issue was the column charset and collate in sql database